# How to send parameters containing objects, arrays to Rails api, so they are parsed?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, uri

*Description:
From Ui (React application) I send an object, containing arrays, in parameters.*

```
 const pkg = {  
   filters: '%7B%7D',      
   lines_per_page: 10,      
   page_number: 1,      
   query: '',      
   sorting: [      
     { field_name: 'created_at', direction: 'ASC' },        
     { field_name: 'csv_file_name', direction: 'ASC' }        
  ]        
 }
```

I convert the field "sorting", using native JS method

```
 encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify(data) )
```

In the end I have a query, which looks like

"page_number=1&query=&sorting=%5B%7B%22field_name%22%3A%22created_at%22%2C%22direction%22%3A%22ASC%22%7D%2C%7B%22field_name%22%3A%22csv_file_name%22%2C%22direction%22%3A%22ASC%22%7D%5D&lines_per_page=10&filters=%7B%7D&"

On api side I get in params something like this with unappropriate symbols.

```
Parameters: {"page_number"=>"1", "query"=>"", "sorting"=>"[{\"field_name\":\"created_at\",\"direction\":\"ASC\"},{\"field_name\":\"csv_file_name\",\"direction\":\"ASC\"}]", "lines_per_page"=>"10", "filters"=>"{}", "upload"=>{}}
```

As I understand there's different encoding and decoding on both sides. May be there's a way to avoid this on UI side or decode properly  on Rails side? What is a good way in such cases?

PS: when I use in Rails to_query or encodeURIComponent() in JS I get different results

Comment: Your const is pkg but you stringify data. The query string doesn't look like a JSON-represenation of an object. You can stringify an object as you do, send it as one parameter and parse it on the Rails side without problems. But its hard to give advise with so little and incomplete code examples.

Comment: Why don't you try sending it as POST data instead of encoded in the URL? Is that an option?

Answer (score 1):

You can decode on Rails side via JSON.parse(params["sorting"])